# 'Display Zoom' iPhone 6/6s setting blurs graphics

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, optimization, uibezierpath

I'm writing a project in Xcode 7 / Swift 2 that it is optimized for iPhone 6/6s (i.e. the project has a launch screen file and launch screen images for iPhone 6/6s).

Fortunately or unfortunately, iPhone 6 users have the ability to turn on the ‘Display Zoom’ setting on device which enlarges elements of the interface. When turned on, this setting effectively enlarges a standard iPhone 5 screen size to fit in the iPhone 6 screen space, upsampling to x1.171875. This upsampling causes elements that are raster based such as images, icons, or views that contain `UIBezierPath()` drawings to display blurred (mildly but noticable).

**A few questions:**

*Appreciate any experienced responses on this conundrum. Thanks.*

1 - How can I instruct elements (e.g. a UIView) on the Storyboard in code to disregard the Display Zoom setting when the user has turned it on?

2 - What techniques are there to ensure pixel perfect accuracy remains when Display Zoom is on? (e.g. Is it possible to render graphics using OpenGL rendering, if so, how?)

3 - Is it possible to replace a x2 image with a x4 image to reduce any blurring when Display Zoom is on? (i.e. will iOS downsample a x4 image to x2 image on iPhone 6?)

4 - How can `UIBezierPath()` drawings maintain pixel perfect accuracy when Display Zoom is on?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing you can do about this. A user who chooses zoomed mode is deliberately throwing away pixel accuracy. The points in the drawing no longer match the pixels on the screen one-to-one (or one-to-two or one-to-three or any integral ratio). This choice therefore blurs the screen for *everything* the user does, not just your app.

Nor can you detect what is happening, because in effect zoomed iPhone 6 is presented to your app as an iPhone 5 (and a zoomed 6 Plus is presented to your app as a 6).

Answer (score 4):

#### As [@matt says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817482/2976878), there's nothing you can do about this for normal UIKit content

However, for Open GL ES or Metal content, you *are* able to [opt-out of the sampling that the device does](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW46), and render straight into the device's physical coordinates - allowing for pixel perfect drawing.

> In a graphics app that uses Metal or OpenGL ES, **content can be easily rendered at the precise dimensions of the display without requiring an additional sampling stage**. This is critical in high-performance 3D apps that perform many calculations for each rendered pixel. Instead, create buffers to render into that are the exact resolution of the display.

---

#### Open GL ES

Set the `contentsScale` of the `CAEAGLayer` to the `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.nativeScale`, or use a `GLKView` which will automatically do this.

You will then want to create your framebuffer with the size of the device's physical coordinates.

---

#### Metal

Set the `contentsScale` of your `CAMetalLayer` to the `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.nativeScale`, or use an `MTKView` which will automatically do this.

You will also want to adjust the drawable size to account for the scale (lifted from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW46)):

```
CGSize drawableSize = self.bounds.size;
drawableSize.width  *= self.contentScaleFactor;
drawableSize.height *= self.contentScaleFactor;
metalLayer.drawableSize = drawableSize;
```

---

See also this [interesting blog post on how the iPhone 6 Plus renders content,](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/11/iphone-6-plus-screen/) plus [the follow-up post specifically about Display Zoom](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/12/pixel-peeping-followup/).

Comment: Thanks originaluser2 , @matt . Yes, an interesting blog read indeed. So to be clear, where would be the best place to set the contentScaleFactor of the UIView-- in viewDidLoad? Also how do I ensure my project is using Metal? My project is in Xcode 7 / Swift 2. I import UIKit.

Comment: @user4806509 I would set the `contentScaleFactor` of your `UIView` or `MTKView` when you create it. If this is in the `viewDidLoad`, then yes that's the best place for it. The only extra setup that I'm aware of when using Metal is to [add it to the required device capabilities array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) in the `Info.plist`, as well as importing the Metal framework as well as MetalKit if you're using it.

Comment: @user4806509 I've also just discovered that `MTKView` and `GLKView` automatically set the content scale for you (it isn't documented as far as I can see, but you can test it if you create a new Metal or OpenGL project from the Xcode templates, which don't explicitly set it). You only have to set the scale on the `CALayer` equivalents.