# Setting CAShapeLayer lineWidth Less Than 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

[image]

In the above screen shot, there are two lines:

1. Solid line is just a `UIView` with 1px height
2. Dashed line is created using this code

---

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *linePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 107)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 107)];

    line.lineWidth = 0.5;
    line.path=linePath.CGPath;
    line.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    line.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    [line setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
    [line setLineDashPattern: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10], [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil]];

    [[self.view layer] addSublayer:line];
}
```

Why is a `UIView` of 1-pixel (`1.0`) height less than a dashed line of `0.5` height?

I want the dashed line to be as slim as solid line.

Comment: Hmm, this image is really not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### When you say the `UIView` has a 1px height, do you *actually* mean 1px?

Sizes in UIKit (the `lineWidth` and `frame` of the `CAShapeLayer` and `UIView` respectively) are measured in [points, not pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7). A single point is equivalent to 1 pixel on a 1x display, 2 pixels on a 2x display and 3 pixels on a 3x display.*

Therefore if you want the size of a single pixel in points - you'll want

```
1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
```

The problem that you seem to be having in your image is that you're confusing the frame origin of your `UIView` with the line of your `UIBezierPath`. These aren't the same. The frame origin represents the *top* of your `UIView` — whereas the line represents the *centre* of your path.

You will therefore want to offset your line position down by half of its width - which will align it to the *centre* of the pixel, allowing the stroke to be rendered on a single pixel.**

**Something like this should achieve your desired result:**

```
CGFloat pixelWidth = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, pixelWidth}];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:v];

UIBezierPath* p = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[p moveToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 50+(pixelWidth*0.5)}];
[p addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){self.view.frame.size.width, 50+(pixelWidth*0.5)}];

CAShapeLayer* s = [CAShapeLayer layer];
s.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; // ensures the CAShapeLayer renders its contents at the logical scale of the screen
s.frame = self.view.bounds;
s.path = p.CGPath;
s.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
s.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
s.lineWidth = pixelWidth;
s.lineDashPattern = @[@10, @10];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:s];
```

Generates the following (on an iPhone 6):

[image]

---

*The iPhone 6 Plus behaves a little differently - its physical display's scale (~2.6x) doesn't match the logical scale (3x).

Therefore any drawing you do in it [can result in pixel bleeding](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/11/iphone-6-plus-screen/), as it gets scaled down to be displayed. You *can* get around this, but it [involves delving into Open GL or Metal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817692/2976878) to do your drawing.

[See also here](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) for a nice overview on how each iPhone renders their content.

---

**On a 2x display, you'll *may* also need to offset the position of your line by an extra 0.25 points in order to prevent pixel bleeding (as your line will lie on a pixel boundary), [as Andrea says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424111/2976878).

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the detailed answer, I tried the 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale and 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
 - 0.25 but both are not working, I have iPhone 6.

Comment: @S.J happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

0.5 point will translate in:

- 1.5px on @3x retina display
- 1px on @2x retina display
- 0.5 on normal display

0.5 is not a physical measure in pixel coordinate system (half pixel doesn't exist), thus the rendering system usually creates an antialiasing around everything that presents a decimal.

This happens also placing `UIView`'s probably you've already seen unwanted blur around them, this happens when the frame has decimal points, usually it can be fixed by passing the frame in the `CGRectIntegral` function.
To draw one pixel line I quote [Apple indications about it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html):

> On a high-resolution display (with a scale factor of 2.0), a line that
>   is one point wide is not antialiased at all because it occupies two
>   full pixels (from -0.5 to +0.5). To draw a line that covers only a
>   single physical pixel, you would need to make it 0.5 points in
>   thickness and offset its position by 0.25 points

Comment: I tried line.lineWidth = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale and line.lineWidth = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale - 0.25 but both are not working.